# why can't change button height when set frame?

Tags: ios, swift

I am testing a sample project with an button . And I write this , but it can't change the button's height .
What's wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var test: UIButton!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    var newFrame = test.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(newFrame.width, newFrame.height * 10)
    test.frame = newFrame
}

}
```

And get the same height I set .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

After calling super. Theoretically you need to wait for the auto layout engine to be done before you modify the frame, otherwise it will be set for you. In this case this is probably what happens as on didLoad the autolayout might not be done yet.

Instead of setting the frame, set the constraints for the button. This way you have full control. Especially when you layout other controls along with your button. Makes your life easier. Mostly.

For your reference check the wwdc sessions about auto layout and adaptive ui.

Hope this helps.